# How to capture event on specified node only?

Tags: javascript, events

I have a markup like this:

```
<div id="largeField">
    <div class="small"></div>
    ......
    <div class="small"></div>
</div>
```

I try to catch `mousemove` on `#largeField` (in vanilla js, but that's not a requirement) with a code like this:

```
largeField.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    var elementData = event.srcElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    var eventX = event.pageX - elementData.left;

    // I just want to get event coordinates to draw something below the mouse

    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventBubble = true;
    return false;
});
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cTrc4/)

The problem is that I don't always get event catched on `#largeField`, but on other `small` elements too.

I don't want to filter on `event.srcElement` inside the callback, because when there will be 1000 of `small` elements, performance would bite.

I'm asking of the right way. I want the callback to be fired only on `#largeField`. I have asked that in the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, not reasonably. The `mousemove` event bubbles, and the only way to prevent that is to hook `mousemove` on all of your "small" elements and cancel the bubbling, which won't help anything and will probably make things worse.

But filtering on `event.target` (not `event.srcElement`, that's IE-only) shouldn't cause a performance problem.

```
largeField.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    if (event.target.id !== "largeField") {
        return;
    }
    // Logic here
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cTrc4/1/)

Comment: I'm sorry, but in your fiddle the `#hover` element doesn't follow the mouse when the mouse if over `.small`.

Comment: @Dan: I was just demonstrating the filtering. You'll need to modify the logic and where (potentially) the filter goes for a complete solution, but that's "left as an exercise for the reader." :-) The fundamental point here is: You have to handle the bubbling, there's no built-in way to say "don't give me bubbling events," and there's no non-bubbling version of `mousemove`.

Comment: I was thinking events are made differently. Just have to update it in my head.

Comment: @Dan: :-) [This diagram](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow) may help some. The "capturing" phase is very, very, very rarely used (and wasn't supported in IE for a long time). Mostly it's the target phase and bubbling phase people use.